# Mac OS X Dock: How to programmatically maximize my application with the application's main icon, and not the minimized icon?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, dock

According to Mac Dock [documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2474): "The Dock keeps applications on its left side, while Stacks and minimized windows are kept on its right. If you look closely, you'll see a vertical separator line that separates them."

Meaning, once the application is minimized, you have a NEW dock icon in the right side, and you need to click on it in order to maximize your application.

However, applications like Chrome and Finder behave differently: if you click on the the LEFT icon (the "main" application's icon), it will also maximize the application!

I have created my own mac application, and I'd like to make it behave like Chrome: meaning once it is minimized, if you click on either the left or right dock icons, it will maximize. How can I do that **programmatically**?

[I am  attaching a dock screenshot. You can see both Chrome "main" icon and "minimized" icon next to it. Both icons will respond and will maximize the window. [image: attaching] 
However other applications (like TextEdit, and also the one I programmed in XCode): only the minimized icon maximizes them. The "main" icon does nothing.]

How can I make both icons maximize my application programmatically?

Thanks a million!

Nili

Comment: Are you using “maximize” as the opposite of “minimize”? Because those aren't actually opposites. Maximizing changes the window's size. (Also, take care not to conflate applications with windows: you can minimize and/or maximize windows; you cannot do either thing to an application.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to implement applicationShouldHandleReopen in order to open minimized windows from the "main" icon

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *) __unused theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (!flag){
        [[self window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the Dock icon calls:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
```

Reopen your windows in this message handler.

It is send to the Application Delegate and is part of the `NSApplicationDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Neither of these methods are called when clicking on the "main" icon :-(

Comment: Sorry, pasted incorrect methods. Answer below should be more helpful.